# A column has been specified more than once in the order by list. Columns in the order by list must be unique

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.2

I am using EF Core 2.2.2 in my project, and I am getting this error when trying to fetch any data from DB, I am not sure what is the reason of this, but it works fine when trying to insert new item to DB:

Error Message :

> "A column has been specified more than once in the order by list.
>   Columns in the order by list must be unique"

I think the issue happened because of using nested OwnsMany many times but not sure:

```
public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using(var context = new OwnsManyIssueContext())
        {
            var accidentEstimationDetails = new List<AccidentEstimationDetails>
            {
             new AccidentEstimationDetails(true, "test1"),
             new AccidentEstimationDetails(false, "test2"),
             new AccidentEstimationDetails(true, "test3")
            };
            var accidentEstimation = new AccidentEstimation(12, 11, accidentEstimationDetails);
            var partiesLiabilityAmounts = new List<PartyAmountDetails>
            {
                new PartyAmountDetails(1,11,120),
                new PartyAmountDetails(1,12,121),
                new PartyAmountDetails(1,10,122)
            };

            var accident = new Accident(accidentEstimation, partiesLiabilityAmounts);

            context.Accidents.Add(accident);
            context.SaveChanges();

            var dbAggregate = context.Accidents.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}

public class Accident
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public AccidentEstimation AccidentEstimation { get; private set; }

    private List<PartyAmountDetails> _partiesAmountDetails;

    public IReadOnlyCollection<PartyAmountDetails> PartiesAmountDetails => _partiesAmountDetails;

    private Accident()
    {
        _partiesAmountDetails = new List<PartyAmountDetails>();
    }

    public Accident(AccidentEstimation accidentEstimation, List<PartyAmountDetails> partiesLiabilityAmount)
    {
        AccidentEstimation = accidentEstimation;
        _partiesAmountDetails = partiesLiabilityAmount;
    }
}

public class AccidentEstimation
{
    public int EstimationPartyId { get; private set; }
    public int FollowerId { get; private set; }

    private readonly List<AccidentEstimationDetails> _details;
    public IReadOnlyCollection<AccidentEstimationDetails> Details => _details;

    private AccidentEstimation()
    {
        _details = new List<AccidentEstimationDetails>();
    }

    public AccidentEstimation(int estimationPartyId, int followerId, List<AccidentEstimationDetails> details)
    {
        EstimationPartyId = estimationPartyId;
        FollowerId = followerId;
        _details = details;
    }
}

public class AccidentEstimationDetails
{
    public bool IsApproved { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    private AccidentEstimationDetails()
    {
    }

    public AccidentEstimationDetails(bool isApproved, string name)
    {
        IsApproved = isApproved;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class PartyAmountDetails
{
    public int ItemTypeId { get; private set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; private set; }
    public decimal? Discount { get; private set; }

    private PartyAmountDetails()
    {
    }

    public PartyAmountDetails(int itemTypeId, decimal amount, decimal? discount)
    {
        ItemTypeId = itemTypeId;
        Amount = amount;
        Discount = discount;
    }
}


public class AccidentTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Accident>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Accident> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Accidents");
        builder.Property(b => b.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); ;
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);

        builder.OwnsOne(a => a.AccidentEstimation, a =>
        {
            a.Property(p => p.FollowerId).HasColumnName("FollowerId");
            a.Property(p => p.EstimationPartyId).HasColumnName("EstimationPartyId");


            a.OwnsMany(dd => dd.Details, dd =>
            {
                dd.ToTable("AccidentEstimationDetails");
                dd.Property<int>("Id");
                dd.HasKey("Id");
            });
        });

        builder.OwnsMany(a => a.PartiesAmountDetails, a =>
        {
            a.ToTable("PartiesLiabilityAmounts");
            a.Property<long>("Id");
            a.HasKey("Id");
        });
    }
}

public class OwnsManyIssueContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Accident> Accidents { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"ConnectionString");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AccidentTypeConfiguration());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason is EF Core bug, caused by the combination of the used owned types. `ToList()` instead of `First()` produces another exception. This is happening even in the latest 2.2.6, so I don't think it will be fixed in 2.x. It works in 3.1, although due to the so many breaking changes and client evaluation removal related issues updating might not be an immediate option.

Comment: Although if you are on 2.2 it's hit EOL and you are supposed to be upgrading to 3.1 https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core